# Incrementing number in filenames in bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to take a list of files and rename them, incrementing a number in their filenames. The directory contains a bunch of files named like:

```
senreg1.csv      senreg2.csv              senreg10.csv
senreg1.csv.1    senreg2.csv.1            senreg10.csv.1
senreg1.csv.2    senreg2.csv.2            senreg10.csv.2
senreg1.csv.3    senreg2.csv.3      ...   senreg10.csv.3
senreg1.csv.4    senreg2.csv.4            senreg10.csv.4
...              ...                      ...
senreg1.csv.10   senreg2.csv.10           senreg10.csv.10
senreg1.csv.11   senreg2.csv.11           senreg10.csv.11
```

I want to increment all of the files that end in 3 or higher so I can insert a new file with suffix 3, so I made a text file called 'renames.txt' containing all the filenames that I want to rename. Then, I tried using a for loop to do the actual renaming.

```
for f in `cat renames.txt`
do
    newfile=`echo $f | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "."}; { printf $1 "." $2 "." $3+1 }'`
    mv "$f" "$newfile"
done
```

I want to end up with something like:

```
senreg1.csv      senreg2.csv              senreg10.csv
senreg1.csv.1    senreg2.csv.1            senreg10.csv.1
senreg1.csv.2    senreg2.csv.2            senreg10.csv.2
senreg1.csv.4    senreg2.csv.4      ...   senreg10.csv.4
senreg1.csv.5    senreg2.csv.5            senreg10.csv.5
...              ...                      ...
senreg1.csv.11   senreg2.csv.11           senreg10.csv.11
senreg1.csv.12   senreg2.csv.12           senreg10.csv.12
```

But instead I get:

```
senreg1.csv      senreg2.csv              senreg10.csv
senreg1.csv.1    senreg2.csv.1            senreg10.csv.1
senreg1.csv.2    senreg2.csv.2     ...    senreg10.csv.2
senreg1.csv.12   senreg2.csv.12           senreg10.csv.12
```

The contents of senregX.csv.12 are the same as the original senregX.csv.3. Hope this explanation made sense. Anybody know what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rename the files in reverse.

```
11 -> 12
10 -> 11
9 -> 10
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

This script do what you want, without temporary files, only to have diversity of solutions:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in $(ls -1 *[0-9]) # list files ending with a number
do 
  # get file name and id
  name=$(echo $file | sed 's/\(.*\)\.\([0-9]\+\)$/\1/g');
  id=$(echo $file | sed 's/.*\.\([0-9]\+\)$/\1/g');

  if [ $id -ge 3 ]
  then
    ((id += 1))

    # We need to backup the files because we may override some files
    cp  $file  "_$name.$id"
  fi
done


# remove old files
for file in $(ls -1 [!_]*[0-9])
do 
  id=$(echo $file | sed 's/.*\.\([0-9]\+\)$/\1/g');

  if [ $id -ge 3 ]
  then
    rm $file;
  fi
done


# finish
for file in $(ls -1 _*[0-9])
do 
  name=$(echo $file | tr -d '_');
  mv "$file" "$name";
done
```